# Unity raycasts going through UI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, raycasting

I am trying to stop a raycast from going through my button 2d UI. Currently, the button works fine when there are no game object behind it, but when there is a game object behind it, it triggers the object and not my button. I have tried using the following code to try to detect the UI, but it does not seem to be working, and constantly returns True:

```
EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

My current code:

```
 void Update () {
    if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId)){
        RegisterModelTouch();
    }

}

public void RegisterModelTouch() {
    // We assume that there was only one touch and take the first 
    // element in the array.

    try {
        Touch touch = Input.touches[0];
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);


        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
           if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Mytag")) {
              //Do model stuff here
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: `IsPointerOverGameObject` is the proper way to do this. You have to post the compete code (raycast + IsPointerOverGameObject code). By the way, what exactly is the raycast used for in your case?

Comment: I am working on an augmented reality application. The raycast is so that users can tap on various parts of the 3d model, and it pops up information about that part. I have a default Physics Raycast component attached to my camera. To keep it simple, I have been printing the value of `isPointerOverGameObject` in `Update()`, which is constantly returning True.

Comment: You need to add the code. Please note that `Input.GetTouch` can only work on mobile devices so make sure you're testing on that

Comment: Yup im testing on an iPad Pro right now. What code do I need? I'm sorry I'm really new to Unity.

Comment: You said your raycast is going through ui? You have to edit your question and add your raycast code + how you are using `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject` to prevent that. There is no code in your question and it's hard for anyonw to help you without that

Comment: Updated with the raycast detection code

Comment: You have to check if `Input.touchCount > 0` and that must be `true` before doing your `IsPointerOverGameObject` check

Comment: I added an if statement for `Input.touchCount > 0`  above the `isPointerOverGambeObject` line and I'm getting the same result.

Comment: Could it be due to the fact that all of my UI elements and Game Objects are children of the same parent element?

Comment: That really shouldn't matter. How about `if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)` then `if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId))`?

Comment: If that doesn't work then something is likely wrong on your side. Is suggest you post screenshot of the "Inspector" tab for both the UI and the other GameOBject. I need to what what components they are both using.

Comment: That seemed to have disabled the GameObjects as well. Here is a screen shot to my Camera, UI and my Object inspector. https://imgur.com/a/FUwv3W5

Comment: When I said UI screenshot I didn't mean Canvas screenshot but that's what you uploaded. I meant your  button 2d UI screenshot. The button you're clicking on....

Comment: Something like this? https://imgur.com/a/EmnlSnx

Comment: @user2901453 he still means a screenshot of the "Inspector" View not the object in the Scene view. Does your button have `Raycast Target` on the `Image` or `Text` component enabled?

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was buried deep in a forum discussion:

```
/// <summary>
/// Cast a ray to test if Input.mousePosition is over any UI object in EventSystem.current. This is a replacement
/// for IsPointerOverGameObject() which does not work on Android in 4.6.0f3
/// </summary>
private bool IsPointerOverUIObject() {
    // Referencing this code for GraphicRaycaster https://gist.github.com/stramit/ead7ca1f432f3c0f181f
    // the ray cast appears to require only eventData.position.
    PointerEventData eventDataCurrentPosition = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
    eventDataCurrentPosition.position = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
 
    List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();
    EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(eventDataCurrentPosition, results);
    return results.Count > 0;
}
```

From here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/ispointerovereventsystemobject-always-returns-false-on-mobile.265372/